# Constructors and destructors

Tags: c++, constructor, eclipse-cdt, destructor

I have the following code and as I knew,at the end of a program which uses class constructors,if certain objects were created,they're destroyed.Judging by that,at the end of the execution I should've had some "~B()" and "~D()" printed out in a particular order but that's not happening when I'm runing the code.Why's that?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class B{
public:
    B(){cout<<"B()";}
    virtual void print(){cout<<"b";}
    ~B(){cout<<"~B()";}
};

class D:public B{
public:
    D(){cout<<"D()";}
    void print(){B::print()
    ;cout<<"d";}
    ~D(){cout<<"~D()";}
    };

void testI(){
    B* b[]={new B(),new D()};
    b[1]->print();
    B&c=*b[1];
    c.print();
}



int main(){
    testI();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `delete` (and `B` requires a `virtual` destructor)?

Comment: Because you are creating objects with `new` and not calling `delete`. Try `int main() { B b; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating your objects with `new`, this means that they are allocated on the heap and NOT the stack and there fore it is up to you to delete them.

```
B * b = new B();
```

Later on..

```
delete b;
```

Edit:

For arrays use:

```
delete[] b; //if b is a pointer to an array of B's
```

Comment: I forgot about the heap.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Because you use dynamic allocation. And for that you are responsible of destroying what you allocate.

read about new and delete here: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/

Answer (score 0):

You're using new to allocate dynamic memory without deleting objects. While you can solve this by adding a delete statement,as your code gets more complex you'll find manual memory management can get unwieldy and error-prone.

You'll be much better off using the automatic memory management classes like  `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`, and using container classes like `std::vector`.

```
void testI()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> b = {std::make_shared<B>(), std::make_shared<D>()};
    b[1]->print();
    B& c= *b[1];
    c.print();
} //b is destroyed here
```

Answer (score 0):

In the norm:

> **3.6.1.5 -** A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function
>   (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration)

So, during your program, you create several variables. When returning from main, only those with automatic storage duration are destroyed. Those with dynamic storage duration are not. For your variables with dynamic storage duration, you have to explicitly call `delete`.

Here is a small example. Put a breakpoint in the destructor and check for m_name value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A
{
public:
    A(const std::string &name):m_name(name){}

    ~A()
    {
        std::cout<<"deleting "<<m_name<<std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::string m_name;
};

A a("Variable at namespace scope");

int main()
{
    A a0("Automatic storage"); 
    A *a1 = new A("Dynamic storage 1"); 
    A *a2 = new A("Dynamic storage 2"); 
    delete a2;
    static A a3("Static storage");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you return from `main` (or call exit), objects with static lifetime will also be destructed.

Comment: It was not the purpose here, but you are right, better to add too. Thanks.

Comment: Not really, but it's a good point as well.  I was actually thinking of variables at namespace scope.

Comment: @JamesKanze: edited. I hope this one it is what you meant^^. Thanks!